# How can I programmatically skip the pink Ubuntu user prompt when using `apt-get`?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, couchdb-2.x

When installing CouchDB 2.1 on Ubuntu using the the `apt-get` package manager, like so:

```
echo "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install couchdb -y
```

I get a prompt screen asking if I would like to install in single node mode, or clustered mode, or if I would like to configure Couch myself. (Not a command prompt, but a pink background with a button that I have to press).

I would like to configure Couch myself, though I need to be able to programmatically skip the review screen (since I'm not running the command myself - the command is part of a script).

How can I specify to automatically specify this option when installing CouchDB 2.1 using `apt-get install couchdb -y`?

Alternatively, would I be forced to install CouchDB from the source if I don't want to manually press the ok button?

Comment: Those sorts of prompts usually have a check to make sure that input is coming from a tty. See what happens if you redirect your script's stdin from somewhere else, or even close it, i.e. `my_script.sh <&-`

Comment: Thank you @ccarton. i tested this by creating a file `x.sh`, with the command `apt-get install couchdb -y`, and then ran the script via `./x.sh <&-`. Didn't work... but did i test correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt you receive comes from the `debconf` system, to configure the package. You can pre-configure the package using `debconf`, so that it doesn't need to ask the questions during installation.  This process is called "preseeding", and is usually done during system installs to preseed all packages on a system at once. But you can do it for a single package, too.

The documentation for preseeding of debconf can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed).